# add new channel fields for existing site

Tags: custom-fields, channel, database

I´ve a site with a channel, this channel has a channel field group with 2 fields. So far, so standard. 
My problem: 
I know exactly, that after some time when the site evolves I´ll ned more channel fields. 
But I don´t know exactly what kind of fields I will need to add. I can be a text field or a textarea or even a file upload field or a matrix. As a startup there will be some pivoting.

My question: If I add a new field, will it be available for all entries in this channel (new and existing) and can users update their entry accordingly. I would send my members a mail saying "we now offer the feature X, go ahead and update your entry".

Will adding channel fields to a channel that has already entries corrupt the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I add a new field, will it be available for all entries in this
>   channel (new and existing) and can users update their entry
>   accordingly

Yes, any new custom fields added to that channel will show up for new & existing entries. Your members will be able to update fine.

If you change a existing field to a new fieldtype (ie. text input ==> Matrix), existing entries will "lose" that data from the text input.